# Intercambiar los datos del arreglo y desplegarlo de forma inversa. JAVA

Tags: java

tengo este código que al principio me pide 3 números que se guardan en un arreglo, lo que quiero hacer es copiar el contenido de ese arreglo e imprimirlo al revés.

EJ. Se captura 1, 2, 3 y lo que debería de ver primero el primer arreglo con la captura: [1, 2, 3] y después inverso: [3, 2, 1]

Funciona bien, el problema es cuando quiero imprimir el arreglo al revés. Si lo hace en `intercambiar()` con el `for` , lo guardo en el 2do arreglo con `nums2[i]=nums1[i]`

De hecho si se fijan en puse `System.out.println(nums2[i]);` para ver si hacía correctamente la inversión. Y si.

Cuando ejecuto el programa , capturo los datos, imprime el PRIMER arreglo(regresando al ejemplo) [1, 2, 3] y después el SEGUNDO pero exactamente igual y en el `println` si lo imprime en la consola como:
3
2
1

Aquí el código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Arreglo7
{
private int numeros1[]; // = new int[3];
private int numeros2[];

public Arreglo7()
{
//  numeros = new int[3];
//  numeros = new int[] {40,20,50};
numeros1 = new int[3]; 

numeros2 = new int[3];

}

private void obtenerDatos( int nums[])
{
    for(int i =0; i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        nums[i]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numeros["+i+"] =")); 
    }
}

private void desplegarDatos(int numbers[])
{
    String str="[";
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<numbers.length-1;i++)
        str = str + numbers[i] + ",";       
        str = str +numbers[i] + "]";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str);        
}

private void intercambiar(int nums1[], int nums2[])
{
//  for(int i=0;i<nums1.length;i++)
    for(int i=nums1.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   
        nums2[i]=nums1[i];
        System.out.println(nums2[i]);               
    }


}

private void principal()
{
    obtenerDatos(numeros1);
    desplegarDatos(numeros1);   
    intercambiar(numeros1, numeros2);   
    desplegarDatos(numeros2);

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Arreglo7 objeto = new Arreglo7();
//  int numeros[] = new int[3];     
    objeto.principal();
}

}
```

Comment: con un factor de cambio en decrremento lo logras

Comment: @srJJ creo que no me entendiste o no me di a entender.  Eso lo tengo. Mi problema es al imprimir ese arreglo.

Comment: Si era lo que te decia, es lo mismo que puso el maestro en la respuesta de abajo, solo que lo hago con dos dos variable distintias, pero igual la del maestro esta muy buena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es de logica..

Estas copiando un array exactamente igual al que tenias, porque por mas que vayas para atras, cuando haces `nums2[i]=nums1[i];` las posiciones a donde va a parar cada item son las mismas.

Cambia tu funcion por:

```
private void intercambiar(int nums1[], int nums2[])
{
    int max = nums1.length-1;
    for(int i=nums1.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   
        nums2[max-i]=nums1[i];  
    }
}
```

De esta forma, recorres el array nums1 para atras, pero copias a la posicion inversa de la que estas buscando cuando vas al array nums2.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en la función intercambiar

```
nums2[i]=nums1[i];
```

Debes cambiar eso por;

```
nums2[]+=nums1[i];
```

Porque estas agregando el valor en el lugar erróneo.

Por ejemplo con el código así si en el arreglo num1 tienes los datos [1,2,3] y dices que la el dato de la posición 2 lo ingresaras en la posición 2 de el arreglo num2 se colocaria en el mismo lugar `num2=[null,null,3]` en la otra vuelta del ciclo se agregara el dato que se encuentra en el arreglo num1 en la posición 1 que es (2) y lo ingresara en la posición 1 del arreglo num2 así que quedará
`num2=[null,2,3]`  y en la otra vuelta obtendría el valor `num2=[1,2,3]` es decir no quedará invertido.